# Somebody use Rode NTG-8 ?

Tags: shotgun, rode, microphone, field-recording

Somebody use [RODE NTG-8](http://www.rodemic.com/mics/ntg8) ? I think new model.

Answer (score 1):

Never noticed they had something like that. While off-topic, I really wish Rode made a M-S shotgun/field mic.

Comment: this! M/S from Rode would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Hi, are you sure you don't mean the NTG-3 (may look like an 8, i guess).  If so, I use this mic often and it sounds fantastic for outdoor booming.  It was a toss up between this mic and the Sennheiser MKH416 and I found that the MKH416 sounded a bit thinner and not as warm as the NTG-3.  A little side note, they used the NTG-3 on "Lost", so booyah to that.

Comment: You might want to look at their website again haha, I was surprised myself when I saw this new mic.

Comment: 8. site says 8 too ;